# Kill the [software-tools] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The tag [software-tools](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-tools) seems like a perfect [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

- It could never be the only tag of a question.
- What are "software tools", even?

People often abuse it for [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec)s. Also, a common mistake is to ask for "a tool that fixes" a symptom, rather than explaining the actual problem.

Therefore: Please nuke this tag.

Comment: `Unable to process the request. Unhandled exception in Tag.Burninate(): no trogdor found.`

Comment: Ah, even good old Trogdor must take a Sunday off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Burninated!]